# Python requests.request ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python-2.7, api, request

I'm working on Entity Extraction usin an API call to https://dandelion.eu/ . I'm sending text files and automatically i get back a json file as response. It's not the first time i use this service and it worked really good. Now I started to send a new set of text file with the same parameters I always used but i get this: ValueError: too many values to unpack.
Here is my code:

```
values={"text":" ",
        "min_confidence":"0.6",
        "include":"types",
        "include":"abstract",
         "include":"categories"
         }

headers = {'X-Target-URI':'https://api.dandelion.eu',
            'Host':'api.dandelion.eu',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            }

for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(spath): #spath is specified 
for file in files:
    if file.startswith("A0"):
        with open(file, "r") as f:
            text = f.read()

            values["text"]= " ".join(text.split())

            #api call
            url = "https://api.dandelion.eu/datatxt/nex/v1/"
            data = urllib.urlencode(values, "utf-8")
            response = requests.request("POST", url, data=data, headers=headers, params=token_api)

            content = response.json()

            print content
```

ErrorValue: too many values to unpack

Can somebody help me on this? I always used the same code for other api calls and it worked good. I don't know what is wrong now.
​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the API returns more than one value.

please refer to API documentation and see what are the return values.

(you did not mentioned what API raised the err in tour question)

Comment: It looks strange because the API give always a single response. A sigle json file. I use the same python script for other text file and it works correctly.

Comment: I discovered what was the problem... The title of my files was serie of increasing numbers, es. 001, 002,003. I don't know why, but when I say to python to open all the files starting with "0", it open all the files one by one but two time tha same file. So it store two files in the variable values["text"]=  " ".join(text.split()) and when i get back the response it's not possible to unpack.